# Unable to access jarfile in Ubuntu, even with full permissions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, jar, executable-jar

I'm fairly new to Linux/Unix and I'm having trouble making a shell script run an executable jar file. This is the content of my shell script start.sh:

```
java -Xmx4096 -Xms4096 -jar "/home/user/Documents/Mserver/fserver.jar"
```

The error I get is

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/user/Documents/Mserver/fserver.jar
```

What I've tried:

I tried running the commands

```
chmod u+x /home/user/Documents/Mserver/start.sh

chmod u+x /home/user/Documents/Mserver/fserver.jar

chmod -R 777 /home/user/Documents/Mserver
```

To give all of my files read, write, and execution permissions

Also, I originally just had the name of the jar file in the shell script and not the whole path it was in. After being told that adding the path may fix the problem, I added it but nothing changed.

When I was looking at another similar question on the site I saw someone was having the same problem with a pearl script and it was because of something with a configuration file, but I have no idea if this is relevant to me at all.

I'm a newbie and I have no idea what to try next, so please let me know if you've noticed anything wrong with how I'm doing this, have any suggestions, or think I left out any important details.

EDIT: When running the command

```
ls -l /home/user/Documents/Mserver/fserver.jar
```

I get the result:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 4883911 Dec 12 17:15 /home/user/Documents/Mserver/fserver.jar
```

And when changing my file to

```
path="$HOME/Documents/Mserver/fserver.jar"
java -Xmx4096 -Xms4096 -jar $path
```

I get still get the error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/user/Documents/Mserver/fserver.jar
```

Also, another thing I forgot to note is when I navigate to the directory where the jar file is and run the command

```
java -Xmx4096 -Xms4096 -jar fserver.jar
```

It works.

Comment: please give us the output of this command `ls -l /home/user/Documents/Mserver/fserver.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line into your shell script:

```
path="$HOME/Documents/Mserver/fserver.jar"
java -Xmx4096 -Xms4096 -jar $path
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the file with the absolute path you use in that script but with that method you know otherwise works.
(so navigate to your directory and run the command you know works:

```
java -Xmx4096 -Xms4096 -jar fserver.jar
```

but with that absolute path you used in that script. In that case:

```
$HOME/Documents/Mserver/fserver.jar
```

)
If that does not work, then the reference is probhably bad.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason of "Error: Unable to access jarfile", when starting Java application from an .sh script was Windows line break characters, `\r` (or CR). It seems that it is passed as a part of the jarfile parameter to Java interpreter, and jar file cannot be found in a filesystem because its name does not match.

To debug this behavior, add the `cd` (change directory) command to the script, run it and observe output, for example:

```
cd /opt/app
java -jar test.jar
```

will give an error text like below (note `\r` at the end of the /opt/app):

```
./test.sh: line 1: cd: $'/opt/app\r': No such file or directory
Error: Unable to access jarfile test.jar
```

I am using Rocky 8 Linux, but this can apply to other distributives too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your problem is like mine or not, but I say my problem and solution may help someone:
I had this error when I wanted to run my shell script to run the Java application:

```
"Unable to access jar file"
```

my problem occurred because I had made the shell script file in Windows so the file had been created with a Windows line ending (CR) while the shell script should be with a Unix line ending (LF), so the solution was changing the line ending to Unix in the Notepadd++ and I saved file and after rerun the problem was solved.